# How to return method type using reflection and use further to invoke methods

Tags: java

code:
I am trying to invoke a method using reflection which returns a interface .

```
I have to use this interface impl to call the methods available in the interface.

Sample code:

 ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
            Class loadedMyClass = classLoader.loadClass("Mainclass");
            Class[] parameterType = {String.class};
            seobj=loadedMyClass.getMethod("getInstance", parameterType).getReturnType();

Mainclass code:

Mainclass has interface myinterface declared.


myinterface getInstance(){

}
i want to invoke getinstance method which returns the myinterface in another class (in another jar) and call the methods present myinterface.

Thanks .
```

Comment: *"i want to **invoke** getinstance method"* So call the [**`invoke(...)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) method on the [`Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) object returned by [`getMethod("getInstance", parameterType)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-). Seems pretty self-evident from the names.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for Quick Reply.   After invoking the method i need to use the return type of that method ,in my case it is a interface .Using this interface i need to invoke the methods available.

Comment: What you get back from the `invoke()` call is an `Object` with the return value, so simply cast to interface. If you don't know the interface at compile-time, then you will of courser also need to use reflection to call the interface methods on that returned object.